# Laravel package, ansi-regex, not save. Severity high, cannot update

Tags: laravel

Whenever I run npm audit I get the following warning:

```
ansi-regex  3.0.0 || 4.0.0 - 4.1.0
Severity: high
 Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-93q8-gq69-wqmw
 Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-93q8-gq69-wqmw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/npm/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/ansi-regex
node_modules/npm/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/ansi-regex
```

I have tried the following:

- npm audit fix (with and without --force).
- removing/reinstalling the    package.
- deleting the lock file and node_modules folder.

This occurred after upgrading from Laravel version 5 to 8.

How can I get rid of this?

Software info:

- Laravel Framework: 8.83.16
- NPM: 8.12.1